# PlayReady DASH playback issue in Edge/IE

Tags: mpeg-dash, playready

What is the error about?

**MSPR_E_NO_DECRYPTOR_AVAILABLE**: Failure occurred when attempting to find a correct PlayReady decryptor object - no decryptor was found. [0x8004B896]

What is PlayReady decryptor object? Is this WRMHEADER or what?

I'm trying to play PlayReady/DASH video in dash.js player. I can see that manifest has been loaded, PlayReady license request-response are happened and correct, EME reports content key is added to media session. But playback not starts but shows the error above.

I can decrypt the content manually by the content key. PlayReady header object is parsable both in manifest and in init segments. Content key checksum is correct.

Comment: Did you try other players, like [Shaka](https://github.com/google/shaka-player) or [Bitmovin](https://bitmovin.com/video-player/) to rule out that it's a bug in the player code (e.g. race condition)?

A changelog entry in the [MS Smooth Streaming Client SDK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cenkd.MicrosoftUniversalSmoothStreamingClientSDK) indicates that such an error could be related to key rotation (`Fixed playback issue with PlayReady keyrotation content (0x8004B896 MSPR_E_NO_DECRYPTOR_AVAILABLE)`) - are you using key rotation?

Comment: Aren't you trying to play something requiring HW PlayReady while your system supports only SW PlayReady?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to play back content for which you do not have a valid content key.  This is very likely due to including license policy that the current machine cannot fulfill.  You should ensure that the policy you have in the license can be fulfilled.